# CSS/Jquery dropdown z-index issue in IE - content being pushed rather than overlayed?

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, z-index

I'm trying to create a simple dropdown menu which, using z-index, should overlay the content below it.  The code below works fine in other browsers but in IE8 (which is my corporate browser) it 'pushes' the content below it.  Based on this code can anyone see why it's doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Jquery:

```
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    //toggle equipment menu
        $('img#PrimarySelectButtonImg').click(function () {
    $('ul#PrimarySelectMenu').slideToggle('fast');
        });
    });
</SCRIPT>
```

CSS:

```
<STYLE>
<!--

a:active, a:focus {
outline: none;
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: 0px;
ie-dummy: expression(this.hideFocus=true);
}
a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: 0px;
}
#PrimarySelectArea {
height: 46px;
width: 272px;
cursor: pointer;
position: relative;
z-index: 100;
}
#PrimarySelectMenu {
display: none;
width: 268px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
background-color: #fff;
}
.the_menu li {
padding: 15px 5px;
display: block;
}
.the_menu li:hover {
background-color: #f1f0ce;
}
.the_menu li a {
color: #666;
text-decoration: none;
}
.the_menu li a:hover {
color: #666;
background-color: #f1f0ce;
}
#MainTableHolder {
position: relative;
z-index: -1;
}
-->
</STYLE>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="kbankContainer">
  <div id="PrimarySelectArea"> <img src="images/PrimarySelectButton.png" width="272" height="38" id="PrimarySelectButtonImg" />
    <ul id="PrimarySelectMenu" class="the_menu">
      <li><a href="#">PRODUCT INFORMATION</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">PROTOCOLS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">FORMS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">INFORMATION</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- begin tools table -->
  <div id="MainTableHolder">
    <table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4 width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th width="36%" align=left>&nbsp;</th>
          <th width="32%" align=left>&nbsp;</th>
          <th width="32%" align=left>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>first row of  table</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried adding the z-index: 100 line to #PrimarySelectMenu (the UL that actually drops down) as well and it still pushed the content down.

Again, thanks for any help!

Comment: What doctype are you using?

Comment: Create a jsfiddle please

Comment: Oh good god.  I wasn't using ANY doctype.  Thanks for your help.  I'm going to go crawl under a rock.

Comment: Did adding a doctype fix it?

Comment: I've tried your code in my windows 7 browser ie 8.0.7600 and its working same as working in other browsers, can you please t

Comment: yes, the doctype fixed it fine.  Sorry for wasting your precious time!